# How to prevent "Error" sound on application exit (from a form called with ShowDialog)

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am creating VB.Net application with multiple forms. On each form there is a button to return to the previous form as well as a button to exit the application entirely. For some reason, no matter how I try to exit the application it will always play the Media.SystemSounds.Hand (Windows "Error" sound) when exiting, which would seem to imply something has gone awry.

I have tried exiting the application in a variety of ways such as:

- Using Application.Exit()
- Looping backwards through each open form and closing each form.
- Closing the main startup form directly.
- Suppressing system sounds.

Important to note, this only happens when the current form was opened with `ShowDialog()`, it does not happen when the current form was called with `Show(Me)`. Reading the interweb about the differences between Show and ShowDialog, pretty much all the information provided simply references the difference between modal and modeless forms, neither of which (for any reason I can tell) should cause said error sound. I should be able to call a modal form and exit the application cleanly without producing an error sound.

I know that in English it seems to make sense that one should be on a main form rather than a dialog form before closing the application, but if the only difference is modal and modeless then this doesn't make sense to me (and ShowDialog should be renamed IMO). Any ideas?

**In one sentence: I would like to be able to exit the application cleanly (no "Error" sound) when closing the application from a form called with `ShowDialog`**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely caused by focus attempting to be passed to the parent form while closing with the `ShowDialog` form still active and the sound is actually the warning sound emitted when you attempt this focus change. Try and close the `ShowDialog` prior to closing its parent form and thus the whole application. This way focus is naturally passed back to the parent form before application exit

Comment: Thanks I will try this when I get back, I have been using a crazy workaround